# How to save an stringbuilder's content to text file using SaveFileDialog?

Tags: winforms, save

This is a winforms application.

In windows, I want the user to click and button, and then a popup should make the user select the path of where they want to save the file.

Answer (score 32):

You want the [WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx) function.

```
using (SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog()) {
    if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {
        File.WriteAllText(dialog.FileName, yourStringBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Think no longer...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2 {
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();

        sb.Append("This is going ");
        sb.Append("to be saved to a text file");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        using (SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog()) {
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                string fileName = dlg.FileName;
                SaveToFile(fileName);
            }
        }
    }

    private void SaveToFile(string fileName) {
        System.IO.TextWriter w = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName);
        w.Write(sb.ToString());
        w.Flush();
        w.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why mess about with StreamWriters when there is a built-in function to do it for you?

Comment: Hey, Pretty cool...I've not seen that function.  I have learned something new today:D

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder.ToString()` can be passed to the `TextStream.Write()` method after creating the file.

Using the [SaveFileDialog class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(VS.80).aspx), you can let the user select path and file name - in a standard way. Detailed examples in the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: The OpenFileDialog will, by default, require the file to exist. The SaveFileDialog class is the way to go.

Comment: the content of the file to be saved is in the stringbuilder

Answer (score 1):

[StringBuilder.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1063zt.aspx)  will get you the string.

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx) will show you how to write text to a file.

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) will show you how to call SaveFileDialog and pass a stream to it to save.

Hope that helps.